# Silverlight PollingDuplex timeouts

Tags: wcf, silverlight, service, pollingduplexhttpbinding

I'm currently working on an application that implements a polling duplex service. I am having issues with the client aborting and I'm not sure why or the right way to handle using the client.

Right now I am getting the client in a hello message like this

```
client = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IDuplexMyClient>();
```

Then I am just hanging on to that in my class and sending things using it like this

```
client.MyFunction(data);
```

There can be any amount of time in between sending data because it depends on user interaction. The problem I am having is I am getting this following error.

```
The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted. polling duplex
```

Is this the incorrect way to handle the client? Any idea why its aborting?

It also seems to do it even when I'm sending messages once a second over it, it seems like it just times out after a little while no matter what.

Comment: It seems that if I change the inactivityTimeout to a very high number this doesn't happen. The thing I don't understand then is what resets this timeout? I'm using the client but it still times out.

Comment: check out sendTimeout, it should be set to 1-2 minutes, also set receiveTimeout to big value like few hours